# pageXOffsetがChrome for Androidでだけ取れない

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

`rect.left + window.pageXOffset + "px"`の値がchrome for androidだけ他のブラウザと違います。
IE11, FireFox, Chrome for windows, FireFox for androidでは期待した値が取れます。
Androidで拡大した時＆＆スクロールした状態でのみ期待した値が取れません。
これは、chrome for androidの仕様でしょうか？
chrome for androidのjavascript仕様のようなものがネットで見つかりますか？
自分では調べ方が分かりません。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: window.pageXOffsetではゼロではない値がchrome for androidで取れています。ゼロを返却している模様ではありません。期待値より大きい値が返されています。ですので、scale factorを試そうかと思いましたが、screen.deviceXDPIはundefinedなので使えません。

Comment: Myakuさんに回答のお礼の一言が抜けていました。ご回答有難う御座います。

Comment: 追記ですが、MyakuさんのCacheコードだと一度画面がスクロールされると２度とスクロールはゼロに帰らない気がしますがね・・

Comment: pageOffsetがゼロを返しているといったことは確認とれていません。現在確認取れているのは拡大すればするほど期待値との差が大きいということです。どなたか解決策をご存知なら教えて頂きたいです。chrome for androidだけで問題が発生しています。

Answer (score 1):

Androidではブラウザで`window.pageXOffset`や`window.pageYOffset`が0を返却する場合があります。

[似たような質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851072/kitkat-webview-incorrectly-reports-pageyoffset)が本家SOにあるのですが、
取得してとれた値を一時的に保存しておくのがオススメです

> ```
> var cachedPosition;
>
> window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
>   var position = window.pageYOffset;
>
>   console.log('position: ' + position);
>
>   if (position === 0) {
>     position = cachedPosition;
>   } else {
>     cachedPosition = position;
>   }
>
>   console.log('cached position: ' + cachedPosition);
> }, false);
> ```